# Matplot lib high resolution in x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, prediction

i have a dataframe with 120 000 rows and i want to plot two features of it over the whole time of 120 000 seconds. It is the Y of my Regression and my prediction of the Random Forest-

I am doing it with this code:

```
laenge_xcheck = list(range(0,len(X_gute_vorhersage),1))
X_gute_vorhersage['Zeit_artificial'] = laenge_xcheck

from numpy import *
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(910,50))
plt.plot(X_gute_vorhersage.Zeit_artificial, X_gute_vorhersage.Y_test, 'r') # plotting t, a separately 
plt.plot(X_gute_vorhersage.Zeit_artificial, X_gute_vorhersage.predicitons_rf, 'b') # plotting t, b separately 
#plt.savefig('test1.png')
plt.show()
```

my goal is to get a picture where i can zoom in with a high resolution, higher than 910,50 - because it is not possible to see a lot with this. I would like to have a really long x axis and a short y and then be able to zoom in. I get it already in this shape:[image]

Is there any possibility to get this in a resolution where i can zoom in and see it in a good resolution. It doesn't matter if the picture gets 200MB. Is there any way to go beyond the size of 910,50 without getting this error message:

```
ValueError: Image size of 72000x3600 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction.
```

Thank you,
R

Comment: Hard to know what the problem is. By default you can always zoom in as much as you want.

Comment: that the resolution i have now with `910,50` is not big enough and if I go higher with the resolution i get an error message: `Image size of 72000x3600 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction.`

Comment: Well the error is clear. You cannot produce an image which is larger than 65535 pixels in any dimension. But of course you can always zoom in as much as you like inside the interactive plotting window.

Comment: What about saving as a pdf? No need for resolution then, because it's a vector graphic

Comment: @user8408080 I get the same error code if I use `plt.savefig('foo.pdf', bbox_inches='tight',dpi=8000)`  -> `It must be less than 2^16 in each direction.`

Comment: What happens if you ommit the `dpi` setting?

Comment: @user8408080 unfourtunately I get the same problem